# Solving system of linear equations involving triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the best way to solve for $\mathbf{A}$ in the system $\mathbf{X=AR}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is square and $\mathbf{R}$ is a upper triangular matrix?

Comment: Depends on what amount of effort you want to put in optimizing this. Backsubstitution is a first approach. But depending on X (sparsity, size), and on your machine, you may improve: use block methods, vector instructions, parallelism, etc.